# flashing led slows down microprocessor

Tags: c++, c, embedded, microprocessors

I've designed a system, when the resistance of the potentiometre is below a set value, the LED blinks `led1 = 1; wait(0.2); led1 = 0 wait(0.2)`, this is what occurs. I need both the wait sequences otherwise the user doesn't see any change. I also have an LCD connected, when the user presses buttons the LCD changes to display different things. The problem is that this change in LCD is significantly slowed down to the `wait(0.2)` statement (0.2second delay). This kind of gives the system a laggy feel. Any ideas what things i can do?

**ISR**
I initially thought about putting the flashing LEDs into an interrupt routine but quickly realized that, if the user didn't change the value of the potentiometre and it was always set to 0, the system would just stay in the ISR.

**Polling**
My second idea was to try polling, make the LED flash every 100th time it came into this function. The results weren't good, it would slow down the system every so often now. When it didn't slow down the system it would go too fast.

Comment: Just about all SoC's have at least one timer that can give you interrupts. Use one such timer for the blinking LED and in the ISR for the timer just toggle the status of the LED.

Comment: *"the system would just stay in the ISR. "* Why would that happen? Assuming you have repeating ISR from hardware timer, ISR could simply be `if(potentioMeter < limit) changeLedState();`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that a hardware timer and an ISR is the way to go. By delaying program execution in the way you are, you *will* experience 'lag' for any other processing, not just the LCD.

The key here is that you need to think about the logic you place in your ISR, so that it doesn't stay there... use a conditional `if` clause or similar to react to what your potentiometer reading is.

Comment: Thank you Ed for your input, I read your answer and am now applying that knowledge onto my system

Answer (score 0):

You need to finish doing your system engineering.

It sounds like you are not using ISRs now, and that can work just fine.  You need to walk your execution paths and understand the worst cases.

Some of this may be an issue of the toolchain+processor.  If polling as you say causes a lag (vs the forced wait loop), then that is likely the processor time for whatever you are doing and will be there in an ISR.  Perhaps I misunderstood.  If your processor+clock+compiler+programming_language+coding_style, etc produces something that cannot do all the tasks in the time needed to do the tasks, adding more stuff (ISRs more polling, etc) is not going to make it go faster.  find the actual problems and attack them, dont just throw in more problems.

Use a hardware timer, you probably have one.  As you walk through your main loop, you check if pot is low, if timer has timed out or if delta from last time to current time is greater than X then change led state and continue on through the loop, dont stop there and wait.  Use a state machine if it makes it easier to program (for some folks a state machine is much harder).

If you have any other wait loops that burn the cpu like this one, use the timer for those as well, dont wait there, come back and check instead.

If the ISR handler doesnt check all the conditions (but the non-isr solution does) add the conditions, if a pot value of 0 is a special case, then have code to check for the special case.  or dont enable the interrupt (or disable it) if the user has set this case.  Basic programming problem, "small matter of programming" to solve it.

Comment: thanks dwelch for your input, i've just being doing this module for 2 months and this is my third assignment. I am going to finish in September so i have a long way to go. I took on board what you said and will implement the ISR routine and the hardware timer. I have implemented these for a different PIC before. I don't have any lag when i delete the built in wait routines in the LED function. 
I will let you know the outcome on monday, thanks for your input. I appreciate it

Comment: you also need to define priorities, is it more important that the led blink rate be accurate enough for the human to not see any variations, or is there something more important and if the led blink rate suffers that is okay...list the tasks this code, prioritize them, and do what you can to honor that.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  Due to the presence of the `wait(0.2)` statement, the LCD refresh is very slow.  The LED statement does not need to be placed in the ISR.  After the LCD refresh, continue to handle the LED in the main while loop (`while(1)`).